# Чтение массива структур

Tags: c, struct, malloc

Привет, пытаюсь вычитать массив структур из бинарника. В итоге читает только одну структуру. в чем ошибка?

```
const struct gItem //proto of event as is with all parameters
{

unsigned int iD;
char name[100];

//event date
unsigned int day;
unsigned int month;
unsigned int year;
unsigned int time; //time counts in minutes

//event parameters
enum gEvType evType;
bool isDelete;

};

const int itemSize = sizeof(struct gItem);
struct gItem (*buffer)[]=NULL;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
int readDb()
{

FILE *db = NULL;

int dbSize = 0;
size_t result = 0;

db = fopen("events.db","rb");

if (db == NULL) {printf("\nFile not Opened\n"); return 1;}

fseek(db, 1, SEEK_END);

dbSize = ftell(db)/itemSize;
printf("dbsize %i\n",dbSize);
rewind(db);

buffer = (struct gItem*)malloc(dbSize*itemSize);
if (buffer == NULL) {printf("\nMem error!!!\n"); return 2;}

result=fread(buffer,1,dbSize,db);
printf("buffersize %i\n",sizeof(buffer));
if (result!=dbSize) {printf("\nReading error!!!\n"); return 3;}

fclose(db);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Так Вы же одну и читаете. Напишете `fread(buffer, dbSize, itemSize, db)` прочтете все dbSize штук.

Comment: @avp Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В своей программе Вы действительно читаете только одну структуру.

В [man 3 fread](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) написано, что функция

`size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream );`

читает  `nmemb` записей (в Вашем случае структур `struct gItem`), каждая длиной `size` байт.
(А у Вас в программе написано `fread(buffer,1,dbSize,db);`, т.е. просите `dbSize` записей размером по 1 байту), что точно соответствует размеру одной `struct gItem`.

На самом деле `fread` читает `size * nmemb` байт, но возвращает количество прочитанных записей (причем **полных**).

Если напишете: `fread(buffer, itemSize, dbSize, db)`, то прочтете все свои `dbSize` структур.

Comment: спасибо, в примере и в самом деле одна стуктура, я сам изменил, чтобы продебажить и забыл. читал весь файл, но в дебаге показывало, что вычитана только одна структура(кьюти), потому я и решил, что прога не правильно работает. Позже продебажился в студии, посмотрел на память, пишется массив структур, так что все работает. спасибо всем за советы.